# Stack Overflow Labs will soon be sponsoring GenAI Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship, announcements

We're excited to announce that [Stack Overflow Labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/) will be sponsoring GenAI Stack Exchange beginning July 25th.

Typically, with site sponsorships, we like to be specific about when they end. As was shared in the [GenAI site announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood), we will be handling sponsorships a little differently for this site:

> We are exploring offering free site sponsorships and ad space on this
> site to new GenAI companies as part of potential co-marketing
> agreements to get some exposure to their users in hopes that they join
> this new community. It won’t be like this forever, and it's not a
> preview of anything to come elsewhere on the network. Just an
> exception we are making here for this site, in this case, to throw a
> broader net to grow its audience. For those unfamiliar with site
> sponsorship on other sites, we usually give quite a bit of heads-up,
> but in this case, the heads-up will maybe be days rather than weeks to
> months, and new partners in this respect could change on a
> week-to-week basis.

For the time being, you will see the [Stack Overflow Labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/) sponsorship and ads on the site. Should these become too intrusive, please do let us know.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown in three places, for the time being. There will be a permanent logo on the right side of the header at the top of the site. A periodic banner will sometimes appear on question pages underneath the question title, and a banner on the right sidebar underneath the Hot Meta Posts section.

[image: Screenshot showing Stack Overflow Labs logo at top-right of page, in banner above question title, and in banner in right sidebar.]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside
> our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the
> questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections
> as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a
> garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits
> still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has
> always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all
> Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for
> sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Comment: Honestly, in terms of sponsorship, this is likely the least disruptive we could hope for.

Comment: Meta.SE reference: [What is Stack Overflow Labs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390241/what-is-stack-overflow-labs): *The purpose is to have a central hub to share our experiments, demos, insights, and news - across all Stack Overflow products. We plan to continually add to this site as we experiment and release new solutions.*